# SQLTable with links to rows in an other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to realize a database for recipes. One table should hold ingredents and its units and the other  should hold recipes for dishes. But somehow I dont know how to realize it. One entry in the dishes table holds a name for the dish and several ids from the ingredents table with a factor (double) that tell how much units of that ingredent.

Now my question is, how can I get this entry for a dish to contain several entries with ingredentID and factor?

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest you to use 3 tables:

1. Dishes (contains dish id, name and some general information)
2. Ingredents (a list of all existing ingredents)
3. Recipiec (table with 3 columns: dish id, ingredent id and number of this ingredent should be used for current dish).

So every dish will have a few rows: one row for each ingredent.

Answer (score 1):

you need at least one more table.

```
dish
-----
dish_id
name
other_things

dish_ingredient
----------------
dish_id
ingredient_id
amount
order?
mixing_instructions?
other_stuff

ingredient
-----------
ingredient_id
other_stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can create three tables for this having many-to-many relationship

The list of all Recipes

```
CREATE TABLE RecipeList
(
    RecipeID INT, 
    RecipeName VARCHAR(50),
    -- .... other fields,
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY (RecipeID),
    CONSTRAINT tb_uq PRIMARY (RecipeName),
)
```

The list of all Ingredients

```
CREATE TABLE IngredientList
(
    IngredientID INT, 
    IngredientName VARCHAR(50),
    -- .... other fields,
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk1 PRIMARY (IngredientID),
    CONSTRAINT tb_uq1 PRIMARY (IngredientName),
)
```

and another table which holds the ingredients for each recipe

```
CREATE TABLE IngredientList
(
    IngredientID INT, 
    RecipeName INT,
    Amount INT,
    Units INT,
    InnerAmountInGrams DECIMAL(10,2),
    -- .... other fields,
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk3 PRIMARY KEY (IngredientID, RecipeName),
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (RecipeID) 
        REFERENCES  RecipeList(IngredientID),
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (RecipeName) 
        REFERENCES IngredientList(IngredientID),
)
```

Comment: Nice but I need unified units for each ingredent because I want to sum up the ingredents in a shopping list.

Comment: Atm with your solution entries for the same ingredents can have different units. But if I want to sum ingredents up, e.g. kg an g should not be mixed. But nice approach, thanks.

Comment: ah, you can tweak your table by adding extra column which holds the converted value of the *unit*, see my updated answer. You can see there is a columnName,  `InnerAmountInGrams`. This is the column where you need to insert the equivalent value for the `Amount` and `Units` converted into `Grams`, so in your case, if you have inserted `1 KG`, in the `InnerAmountInGrams`, you will put there `1000`. So it is easy to sum up the value `:D`